# Find data in database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, sqlcommand

I have an idea of what supposed to do just not exactly sure how to put it all together.  I'm trying to search records in my data using a text box.  I would like if the user didnt know the whole address just to be able to enter a portion of the address and still return records.  If I enter the full address then a record returns.  But if I just enter the first couple letters and search nothing returns.

Thanks

Here is what I have :

```
protected void btnFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string searchFor = txtFirstName.Text.Trim();
        int results = 0;
        string errorText = "No records found";

        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Contacts.mdb");
        conn.Open();

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        string cmd = "SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE Address LIKE '+searchFor ' ";

        OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd, conn);

        da.Fill(ds, "Search");

        DataRow[] row;
        DataRow dr;

        row = ds.Tables["Search"].Select("Address='" + searchFor + "'");
        results = row.Length;

        if (results > 0)
        {
            dr = row[0];
            txtFirstName.Text = dr["FirstName"].ToString();
            txtLastName.Text = dr["LastName"].ToString();
            txtEmail.Text = dr["Email"].ToString();
            txtAddress.Text = dr["Address"].ToString();
            txtPhone.Text = dr["Phone"].ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = errorText;
        }
        conn.Close();


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** you are misusing single quotes in your query. you need to wrap up the string variables with single quotes.

**2.**  you are not properly adding parameter in your query. you need to close parameter
   with concatenation `+` operator

**3.** you need to use `%` for searching.
example : if you want to search in between you can use `%` before and after your search string

This

```
string cmd = "SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE Address LIKE '+searchFor ' ";
```

should be

```
string cmd = "SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE Address LIKE '%"+ searchFor +"%'";
```

Comment: I made the changes but still the same result.  My else statement fires and the no records message appears

Answer (score -1):

You could try this code:

```
 string cmd = "SELECT * FROM Contact WHERE Address LIKE '%"+ searchFor +"%'";
```

Comment: I'll remove the downvote when the code looks like it will compile and work.